# iOS app crashes on calendar.dateComponents

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I'm having a crash on this line of code and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: start, to: end!)
```

This only happens on some devices and does not happen all of the time.

Full code:

```
    let start = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"
    let end = formatter.date(from: dateString)

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: start, to: end!)
```

`dateString` is `5/3/17 7:00 PM`

What could be causing the issue?

Comment: What's the error? And make sure `end` isn't `nil`. Remember, the `!` operator means "crash here if nil".

Comment: Using the `dateString` value you provided (5/3/17 7:00 PM), I am able to run your code fine in a playground. There is no crash. But you do mention that this only happens on some devices. On those devices, do you know whether the time is in 24-hour or 12-hour format? Are you able to check?

Comment: Please post the full error message. Don't make us guess what the error is.

Comment: The error message is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` - it happens when the device date format is in 24-hour mode because the `end` date becomes `nil`

Comment: try setting your formatter locale `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: You need to redo your question to be about the actual issue which is about the date formatter. Your issue has nothing to do with the date components (other than your bad use of force unwrapping).

Comment: @Fahim it has nothing to do with the user settings

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually, it is the user setting which results in this crashing on some devices and not crashing on others. Your solution is correct but most people don't set the locale and the date formatter works till they hit 24-hour format. I say this because I've run into this several times :)

Comment: it all depends on were the string it is coming from

Comment: @LeoDabus That is not correct. The string origin has nothing to do with it. Try the same string on a device with 12-hour and 24-hour date format set and without the locale set for the date formatter and you'll see the crash. So it depends on the device the code is running on - not the source of the string.

Comment: that string as it is will always work as it is if he sets the locale. What I mean is if the string comes from date formatter then the user setting will affect the string and only if he uses date and time style properties

Comment: Yes, but the cause of the crash is the user setting on the device *and* the lack of locale on the date formatter. What I was disputing was you saying that the user setting has nothing to do with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the following two lines of code, when the device you are running on is in 24-hour clock mode.

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"
let end = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

When in 24-hour mode, the second line returns `nil` for the date, and as @rmaddy warns above in the comments, forcing optionals is not a good idea since that can result in runtime crashes :)

**Update:**
I wanted to check the code to make sure that the crash goes away before I added this but as @LeoDabus states, adding the following line should fix the crash:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Comment: This is a comment, not a solution to the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I wanted to add the solution as an update once I tested the code. I have added the solution now.